# ASUS PRIME B350-Plus motherboard cannot detect M.2 2280

Tags: ssd, motherboard, m.2, amd-ryzen

Motherboard ASUS PRIME B350-PLUS with Ryzen 1700 cannot detect M.2 2280 ADATA XPG SX6000 Pro (NVMe). OS (Windows 10) - the same. My steps were:

1. I've removed any SATA cables from SATA5/SATA6 ports (as described in the manual: *"The M.2 Socket shares bandwidth with the SATA6G_5/6 ports, therefore the SATA6G_5/6 ports cannot be used when a SATA/PCIE mode M.2 device is installed"*
2. I've updated BIOS upto current version
3. I've checked all the BIOS options regarding M.2. The all are on.

   Still not working.
4. Move the videocard to the another PCI-E Slot. No difference.
5. All options with UEFI are set on now. Still no difference.
6. Letter to ASUS support :). Waiting for answer.
7. Turned off Security Boot. Deleted all the security keys. Set OS to Non-Windows OS. Difference: There are NVM Express device driver (non working) in the Windows Device manager. Error code: 10.

Screenshots from BIOS:

1. No device in M.2 slot:

   [image: no device in M.2 slot:]
2. Presence in the BIOS boot menu (the fifth):

   [image: but presense in the BIOS boot menu]

Any ideas to do? Now I plan to make bootable Linux USB and try to test this card with Linux.

P.S. Tested M.2 card on two other m/boards - it works. It works as native NVMe and in SATA emulation mode too.

Comment: https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/PRIME-B350-PLUS/specifications/ Read carefully the specs regarding your CPU and what precisely M.2 the motherboard supports with it.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Yes, I've read that. All is correct in my hardware with specs to my mind

Comment: “but only in boot menu.” - As apposed to what exactly? SATA or NVMe?  NVMe requires UEFI mode to be enabled

Comment: @Ramhound UEFI mode is enabled in all places I've found. BIOS has no option "Use NMVe as SATA".

Comment: What?  There are two types of M.2 drives SATA and NVMe.  I was asking what type of SSD you purchased.  I further stated that NVMe requires UEFI mode.

Comment: @Ramhound I have other m/b. It has option in BIOS "Use NMVe as SATA'. I think - it's emulations for older OSes.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov - That option isn’t compatible with your drive.  What are you trying to do exactly, I asked before, and you never replied to my question with an answer that was adequate

Comment: @Ramhound Edited the question. Added all I made.

Comment: You need to change your boot order.  I still suspect you have Legacy/Compatibility Mode enabled

Comment: @Ramhound I have received the answer from ASUS support. It's very surprising for me. Yes it helped me out (I'll write about it here tomorrow) but to my mind it is very specific for this m/b

Answer (score 0):

Well. I am disappointed with the technical support answer: this motherboard works with this card type only if the card is bootable and the system loaded from it. It is possible that in the future the BIOS will be redesigned, but not at the current moment . However, I doubt that the problem will be solved in the future, since the motherboard is quite old.
So I have to clone my system drive to this M.2 card on another computer, and then use the card on my system.

Comment: The response you got from ASUS isn’t accurate.  There absolutely is no reason you cannot select that drive from a UEFI compatible OS installation environment provided UEFI mode is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble. My new Nvme drive is not shown as a drive, but I could make a clean installation of win10 with this steps:

- Enter the bios, and disable SATA devices
- Start installation with USB drive
- Win 10 installation only detects nvme drive
- Run normal installation
- Check BIOS for Booting options and enable other SATA devices
- Restart
  Just in case, my config is:
  AMD Ryzen 2400g, 16gb Ram 2400mhz
  Asus B350 prime plus
  Geforce GTX 950
  Drives: Nvme 500gb and SATA2 mechanic drive 2tb

Answer (score 0):

You needed to enable the NVMe driver ... it will still show as having no NVMe drive in.

Go to Boot > Boot configuration (between fast boot and CSM)

Down at the bottom turn

AMI Native NVMe Driver Support. ON (grey background)

You will still see it as not present in the Advanced/SATA Configuration

When you start your OS, it will be there.